# Background Image moves together with content on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have a problem with jquery code on website where i have wordpress.
This is my fiddle:

```js
$('.test1').scroll(function() {
  var x = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(this).css('background-position', '0% ' + parseInt(-x / 10) + 'px');
});
```

```css
.test1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff url(http://imgie.pl/images/2017/10/11/pieczatki-w-tlev2c3b6c.png) no-repeat fixed center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor varius, scelerisque a, bibendum scelerisque pede turpis sed est. Aliquam eleifend mi, ut orci sit amet, purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per inceptos hymenaeos. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    eget, faucibus eros lacus, congue ut, consequat auctor auctor odio. Aliquam orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et malesuada enim non magna. Aliquam erat urna, id sollicitudin magna. Vestibulum ante sit amet, vestibulum ipsum. Morbi tincidunt. Fusce
    condimentum sem vel purus. Pellentesque vel purus. Phasellus vitae metus. Curabitur blandit egestas purus. Aenean ligula quis wisi. Mauris vitae arcu nec pede. Morbi nibh justo, eget est. Pellentesque mattis lorem non enim. Etiam non odio. Etiam rutrum.
    Nunc arcu erat lacus, congue sit amet ligula. Suspendisse justo nibh, mollis faucibus, convallis tellus. Integer sollicitudin quis, tellus. Aenean nulla orci quis sem. Pellentesque egestas ac, augue. Vestibulum sollicitudin. Donec lectus dapibus nisl.
    Nam sed est dolor, scelerisque iaculis. Pellentesque laoreet condimentum, urna ut justo quis venenatis eu, pulvinar ligula, nonummy at, suscipit ultricies, velit eleifend et, tincidunt consequat, orci ultricies libero laoreet ante in erat ac dolor.
  </p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor varius, scelerisque a, bibendum scelerisque pede turpis sed est. Aliquam eleifend mi, ut orci sit amet, purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per inceptos hymenaeos. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
  eget, faucibus eros lacus, congue ut, consequat auctor auctor odio. Aliquam orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et malesuada enim non magna. Aliquam erat urna, id sollicitudin magna. Vestibulum ante sit amet, vestibulum ipsum. Morbi tincidunt. Fusce
  condimentum sem vel purus. Pellentesque vel purus. Phasellus vitae metus. Curabitur blandit egestas purus. Aenean ligula quis wisi. Mauris vitae arcu nec pede. Morbi nibh justo, eget est. Pellentesque mattis lorem non enim. Etiam non odio. Etiam rutrum.
  Nunc arcu erat lacus, congue sit amet ligula. Suspendisse justo nibh, mollis faucibus, convallis tellus. Integer sollicitudin quis, tellus. Aenean nulla orci quis sem. Pellentesque egestas ac, augue. Vestibulum sollicitudin. Donec lectus dapibus nisl.
  Nam sed est dolor, scelerisque iaculis. Pellentesque laoreet condimentum, urna ut justo quis venenatis eu, pulvinar ligula, nonummy at, suscipit ultricies, velit eleifend et, tincidunt consequat, orci ultricies libero laoreet ante in erat ac dolor.
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor varius, scelerisque a, bibendum scelerisque pede turpis sed est. Aliquam eleifend mi, ut orci sit amet, purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per inceptos hymenaeos. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    eget, faucibus eros lacus, congue ut, consequat auctor auctor odio. Aliquam orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et malesuada enim non magna. Aliquam erat urna, id sollicitudin magna. Vestibulum ante sit amet, vestibulum ipsum. Morbi tincidunt. Fusce
    condimentum sem vel purus. Pellentesque vel purus. Phasellus vitae metus. Curabitur blandit egestas purus. Aenean ligula quis wisi. Mauris vitae arcu nec pede. Morbi nibh justo, eget est. Pellentesque mattis lorem non enim. Etiam non odio. Etiam rutrum.
    Nunc arcu erat lacus, congue sit amet ligula. Suspendisse justo nibh, mollis faucibus, convallis tellus. Integer sollicitudin quis, tellus. Aenean nulla orci quis sem. Pellentesque egestas ac, augue. Vestibulum sollicitudin. Donec lectus dapibus nisl.
    Nam sed est dolor, scelerisque iaculis. Pellentesque laoreet condimentum, urna ut justo quis venenatis eu, pulvinar ligula, nonummy at, suscipit ultricies, velit eleifend et, tincidunt consequat, orci ultricies libero laoreet ante in erat ac dolor.
  </p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor varius, scelerisque a, bibendum scelerisque pede turpis sed est. Aliquam eleifend mi, ut orci sit amet, purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per inceptos hymenaeos. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
  eget, faucibus eros lacus, congue ut, consequat auctor auctor odio. Aliquam orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et malesuada enim non magna. Aliquam erat urna, id sollicitudin magna. Vestibulum ante sit amet, vestibulum ipsum. Morbi tincidunt. Fusce
  condimentum sem vel purus. Pellentesque vel purus. Phasellus vitae metus. Curabitur blandit egestas purus. Aenean ligula quis wisi. Mauris vitae arcu nec pede. Morbi nibh justo, eget est. Pellentesque mattis lorem non enim. Etiam non odio. Etiam rutrum.
  Nunc arcu erat lacus, congue sit amet ligula. Suspendisse justo nibh, mollis faucibus, convallis tellus. Integer sollicitudin quis, tellus. Aenean nulla orci quis sem. Pellentesque egestas ac, augue. Vestibulum sollicitudin. Donec lectus dapibus nisl.
  Nam sed est dolor, scelerisque iaculis. Pellentesque laoreet condimentum, urna ut justo quis venenatis eu, pulvinar ligula, nonummy at, suscipit ultricies, velit eleifend et, tincidunt consequat, orci ultricies libero laoreet ante in erat ac dolor.
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor varius, scelerisque a, bibendum scelerisque pede turpis sed est. Aliquam eleifend mi, ut orci sit amet, purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per inceptos hymenaeos. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    eget, faucibus eros lacus, congue ut, consequat auctor auctor odio. Aliquam orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et malesuada enim non magna. Aliquam erat urna, id sollicitudin magna. Vestibulum ante sit amet, vestibulum ipsum. Morbi tincidunt. Fusce
    condimentum sem vel purus. Pellentesque vel purus. Phasellus vitae metus. Curabitur blandit egestas purus. Aenean ligula quis wisi. Mauris vitae arcu nec pede. Morbi nibh justo, eget est. Pellentesque mattis lorem non enim. Etiam non odio. Etiam rutrum.
    Nunc arcu erat lacus, congue sit amet ligula. Suspendisse justo nibh, mollis faucibus, convallis tellus. Integer sollicitudin quis, tellus. Aenean nulla orci quis sem. Pellentesque egestas ac, augue. Vestibulum sollicitudin. Donec lectus dapibus nisl.
    Nam sed est dolor, scelerisque iaculis. Pellentesque laoreet condimentum, urna ut justo quis venenatis eu, pulvinar ligula, nonummy at, suscipit ultricies, velit eleifend et, tincidunt consequat, orci ultricies libero laoreet ante in erat ac dolor.
  </p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor varius, scelerisque a, bibendum scelerisque pede turpis sed est. Aliquam eleifend mi, ut orci sit amet, purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per inceptos hymenaeos. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
  eget, faucibus eros lacus, congue ut, consequat auctor auctor odio. Aliquam orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et malesuada enim non magna. Aliquam erat urna, id sollicitudin magna. Vestibulum ante sit amet, vestibulum ipsum. Morbi tincidunt. Fusce
  condimentum sem vel purus. Pellentesque vel purus. Phasellus vitae metus. Curabitur blandit egestas purus. Aenean ligula quis wisi. Mauris vitae arcu nec pede. Morbi nibh justo, eget est. Pellentesque mattis lorem non enim. Etiam non odio. Etiam rutrum.
  Nunc arcu erat lacus, congue sit amet ligula. Suspendisse justo nibh, mollis faucibus, convallis tellus. Integer sollicitudin quis, tellus. Aenean nulla orci quis sem. Pellentesque egestas ac, augue. Vestibulum sollicitudin. Donec lectus dapibus nisl.
  Nam sed est dolor, scelerisque iaculis. Pellentesque laoreet condimentum, urna ut justo quis venenatis eu, pulvinar ligula, nonummy at, suscipit ultricies, velit eleifend et, tincidunt consequat, orci ultricies libero laoreet ante in erat ac dolor.
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor varius, scelerisque a, bibendum scelerisque pede turpis sed est. Aliquam eleifend mi, ut orci sit amet, purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per inceptos hymenaeos. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
    eget, faucibus eros lacus, congue ut, consequat auctor auctor odio. Aliquam orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et malesuada enim non magna. Aliquam erat urna, id sollicitudin magna. Vestibulum ante sit amet, vestibulum ipsum. Morbi tincidunt. Fusce
    condimentum sem vel purus. Pellentesque vel purus. Phasellus vitae metus. Curabitur blandit egestas purus. Aenean ligula quis wisi. Mauris vitae arcu nec pede. Morbi nibh justo, eget est. Pellentesque mattis lorem non enim. Etiam non odio. Etiam rutrum.
    Nunc arcu erat lacus, congue sit amet ligula. Suspendisse justo nibh, mollis faucibus, convallis tellus. Integer sollicitudin quis, tellus. Aenean nulla orci quis sem. Pellentesque egestas ac, augue. Vestibulum sollicitudin. Donec lectus dapibus nisl.
    Nam sed est dolor, scelerisque iaculis. Pellentesque laoreet condimentum, urna ut justo quis venenatis eu, pulvinar ligula, nonummy at, suscipit ultricies, velit eleifend et, tincidunt consequat, orci ultricies libero laoreet ante in erat ac dolor.
  </p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet tempor varius, scelerisque a, bibendum scelerisque pede turpis sed est. Aliquam eleifend mi, ut orci sit amet, purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per inceptos hymenaeos. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
  eget, faucibus eros lacus, congue ut, consequat auctor auctor odio. Aliquam orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et malesuada enim non magna. Aliquam erat urna, id sollicitudin magna. Vestibulum ante sit amet, vestibulum ipsum. Morbi tincidunt. Fusce
  condimentum sem vel purus. Pellentesque vel purus. Phasellus vitae metus. Curabitur blandit egestas purus. Aenean ligula quis wisi. Mauris vitae arcu nec pede. Morbi nibh justo, eget est. Pellentesque mattis lorem non enim. Etiam non odio. Etiam rutrum.
  Nunc arcu erat lacus, congue sit amet ligula. Suspendisse justo nibh, mollis faucibus, convallis tellus. Integer sollicitudin quis, tellus. Aenean nulla orci quis sem. Pellentesque egestas ac, augue. Vestibulum sollicitudin. Donec lectus dapibus nisl.
  Nam sed est dolor, scelerisque iaculis. Pellentesque laoreet condimentum, urna ut justo quis venenatis eu, pulvinar ligula, nonummy at, suscipit ultricies, velit eleifend et, tincidunt consequat, orci ultricies libero laoreet ante in erat ac dolor.
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I've tried do that background image will move together with content on scoll but it doesn't work. On other fiddle this code worked perfectly but I want to do this in wordpress and there thats code doesn't work. Can u help me guys ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood by your question, you should use CSS instead of JS to achieve this:

```
.test1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff url(http://imgie.pl/images/2017/10/11/pieczatki-w-tlev2c3b6c.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

`background-attachment: fixed` is the key here

And with this, your jquery code is of no use.

Comment: Could you send me a link to your wordpress site or something. Anything that'll help me take a look

Comment: OK I think that I got this but have one more question. Is it possible to do that background-image will be over text ? I think that it's impossible cuz it is background-img, ye ?

Comment: there's a reason it's called a background image :D